# turtlemimic.launch problem

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello!

i am currently working with the tutorials and i got stuck. Let me explain the problem:
in the tutorial about roslaunch it says "now let's create a launch file called turtlemimic.launch and paste the following:..... "
i created the file using "touch turtlemimic.launch.xml" and i wrote the code using nano.
when i type  "roslaunch beginner_tutorials turtlemimic.launch" i get:
[turtlemimic.launch] is neither a launch file in package [beginner_tutorials] nor is [beginner_tutorials] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

I dont get what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237461/turtlemimic.launch-problem/) by [nikos_kar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27220/nikos_kar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Launch files have a `.launch` extension. Only give launch files a `.xml` extension if you don't want them to be included in the auto-complete list (ie: when you press `tab tab`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0